# Tomcat not converting .jsp into a servlet?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, struts

I'm pretty new to servlets so be patient with me.  I created a .jsp in eclipse and added it under `/webapps` in Tomcat.  From my understanding, Tomcat should convert that .jsp to a servlet and place it under `/work` at runtime.

I'm coding in Eclipse and also launching Tomcat from there, however, I have to copy the files from my workspace and manually paste them into my Tomcat folder (fear of mixing wrong files in a shared repo).  I place the .jsp where all the others are located (others that were created by work partners), however, Tomcat is not creating the .java file for it.

Anyone have any guidance they could lend?  Again, I'm really new to all of this so I'm sorry if some of it doesn't make sense.  Thanks!

Edit:  I'm using Apache Struts and I'm getting the error Failed to open `http://localhost:8080/aexportal/ProcessEmailTrace.do` when debugging.  I changed up the `struts-config.xml` file to what I assume is correct (based on what my coworkers did).  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  I failed to add all of the required files in the Tomcat folder that were referenced in my file.  Once I added all the files in, it works (almost) perfectly!